# Multithreading in Powershell Invoke-Command

Tags: multithreading, powershell

```
Function A{
    ...}
Function B{
    ...}
Function C{
    ...}

$Servers = "Server1","Server2","Server3",... 

ForEach($server in $servers){
  $Session = New-PSSession $server
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${Function:A} -Session $Session
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${Function:B} -Session $Session
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${Function:C} -Session $Session
}
```

I am running a script with functions and invoking them on a jumpoint to several servers.
In this case, Invoke-command works sequentially, invoking function A then B then C onto the servers.
How can I invoke them in parallel?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use server array directly in invoke-command

```
$servers = 'server1','server2','server3','server4'
$cred = Get-Credential
function a {
echo "Function a $env:COMPUTERNAME"
}
function b {
echo "Function b $env:COMPUTERNAME"
}
function c {
echo "Function c $env:COMPUTERNAME"
}
# Put function definition to import in script block
$allFunctionDefs = "
    function a { ${function:a} }; 
    function b { ${function:b} }; 
    function c { ${function:c} }
"
# Run function
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {
    Param( $allFunctionDefs )
    . ([ScriptBlock]::Create($allFunctionDefs))  
    a
    b
    c
} -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $allFunctionDefs
```

Comment: I agree with you, but my functions actually contain booleans and lots of other stuff. So when I run the command you just wrote, it bugs.